# Rails : Cannot print out sql request fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I set up rails connecting to windows mssql 2005. I have an employee table which schema looks a little bit like. I am trying to get an Employee then displaying the Employee's name in a webpage. Yet the page only renders the objects name "Employee". More details below.

```
  create_table "EMP", primary_key: "EMP_EmployeeID", force: true do |t|
    t.decimal  "EMP_HourlyNormalRate",                     default: 0.0,   null: false
    t.decimal  "EMP_HourlyOvertimeRate",                   default: 0.0,   null: false
    t.decimal  "EMP_HourlyPremiumRate",                    default: 0.0,   null: false
    t.string   "EMP_LastName",                                             null: false
    t.string   "EMP_FirstName"
    t.string   "EMP_MidName"
    t.string   "EMP_Address",                  limit: 50
    t.string   "EMP_City",                     limit: 30
#Continues/MoreFileds........
```

Now I have a model that looks something like this.

```
class Emp < ActiveRecord::Base

   self.table_name = "EMP"
  primary_key = 'EMP_EmployeeID'

end
```

In the controller I search for an employee using a primary key which returns a successful object.

I render it on the page like this.

```
<h1> Employee <%@emp.inspect%> </h1>
<h1> Employee <%@emp.EMP_FirstName%> </h1>
```

Sadly the two html tags print out Employee. I try other fields and they print out Employee. Do I need to define things more in my model.

Comment: You need to use `<%= %>` instead of just `<% %>` to output value.  Use `<%= @emp.inspect%>` and `<%= @emp.EMP_FirstName%>`

Comment: Something as simple as that. Funny thing is although it finds the employee, it prints out nil anyway. then I just grabbed them all the employees and used the for each construct and they seem to be printing out the fields

Comment: You probably need to show us your controller so we can understand how `@emp` is getting set.